# XSLT check if String is inside a set

Tags: java, xml, excel, xslt, saxon

I am trying to check if a String is contained within a set. I have an Excel sheet that I convert to an `xml` file; example:

Excel sheet on left and converted sheet on right (`RowData.xml`):

[image: ExcelXML]

So I have an `xml` file where those set of numbers may or may not be there. For example, the source `xml` may look like this:

Source.xml:

```
<Data>
    <Number>5556781234</Number>
    <Number>5556781235</Number>
    <Number>5556781236</Number>
</Data>
```

As you see it can stop anywhere. The source `xml` file may have all the numbers listed in `RowData.xml` or it may have only 1 or more. So my question is, how would I check for that in my `xslt` file?

I want to do this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<!-- This is the Excel sheet converted to an XML file -->
<xsl:param name="sheet-uri" select="'RowData.xml'"/>
<xsl:param name="sheet-doc" select="document($sheet-uri)"/>

<xsl:template match="Data">
    <xsl:for-each select="Data/Number">
        <xsl:variable name="continue" select="$sheet-doc//Sheet/Row[Number = current()]/Continue"/>

        <xsl:if test="">
            <!-- Check the Source.xml against the RowData.xml and 
                 see if the set contains any "No"'s in it. -->

            <!-- If it does then don't do the following -->

            <Data2>
                <Number><xsl:value-of select="Number"/></Number>
                <Timestamp>125222</Timestamp>
            </Data2>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

So basically, before making the `<Data2>` element, check the numbers in `Source.xml` and see if any of those numbers have a value of `No` for the column `Continue` in `RowData.xml`. I don't know how to make the `if` statement above. I know there's a `contains()` function in `xslt`; however, I don't know how I can use it here.

Is this possible? Please let me know if anything was confusing. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> check the numbers in Source.xml and see if any of those numbers have a value of No for the column Continue in RowData.xml.

You can take advantage of XSLT's "existential equal" operator here:

```
test="doc('source.xml')/Data/Number = 
    $sheet-doc//Sheet/Row[Continue='No']/Number"
```

Essentially, if A and B are sets of values, then A = B returns true if some value in A is equal to some value in B.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this looks like it can work! However, Is there another way to write `doc('source.xml')/Data/Number`? In my Java code I convert the file to a String and parse it using the `Document` class then transform by passing it as a `DOMSource(document)`. For example, a `this` function would be great.

Comment: You really don't want to be creating a DOM if the only reason is to run an XSLT transformation. With Saxon, transforming a DOM takes 5-10 times as long as using Saxon's own native tree model. Try switching to the s9api interface and creating the tree using a DocumentBuilder, then passing it in as a stylesheet parameter.

Comment: I switched to s9api but the `test` statement above keeps returning `false` (It's the same with my old code). I set the parameter through Java code with the file path to the document. The only thing I changed in the statement is the beginning part: `doc($source-xml)...`. The parameter name is `$source-xml`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, it's very difficult to debug code when what you're working with is some different code and a description of what you changed. To find what you did wrong, I need to see *exactly* what you did.

Comment: Oh, I figured it out. It was a simple typo. Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use the **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#key)** mechanism - esp. if you're using XSLT 2.0.

Define a key as:

```
<xsl:key name="row" match="Row" use="Number" />
```

then do:

```
<xsl:template match="/Data">
    <xsl:for-each select="Number[not(key('row', ., $sheet-doc))]">
        <Data2>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            <Timestamp>125222</Timestamp>
        </Data2>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

This selects only `Number`elements that do not have a corresponding `Row` in the `RowData.xml` document.

Comment: I don't quite understand your last sentence. If I go by the example given with `Source.xml`, the `for-each` statement will only select the `<Row>` tags that match with the Numbers in `RowData.xml`?

Comment: No, it selects all others. That's because your comment says "*If it does then don't do the following*". My code says: *If it doesn't,  then do the following*.

Comment: Ohh ok. If I took out the `not` then I would get all the numbers that match the ones in `Source.xml`? From there, I can check if that set has any *Continue* that equals *No*?

Comment: Something like this: `Number[(key('row', ., $sheet-doc))]/Continue = 'No'`?

Comment: If you want to match only Rows where Continue = No, you can narrow the key to: `<xsl:key name="row" match="Row[Continue = 'No']" use="Number" />`.  -- Your version should work too, I think.

Comment: From there I can do `select="Number[(key('row', ., $sheet-doc))]`, which will give me all the Rows that have a *no* for *Continue*? Otherwise, it means that all the *Continue*'s were *Yes*? Thanks for all the help by the way!

Comment: After correcting the key, `select="Number[(key('row', ., $sheet-doc))]` will select all `Number`s that have at least one "related" (i.e. same Number value) `Row` with Continue = No,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116234/discussion-between-m-o-and-michael-hor257k).

Comment: Let us not. Just try it.

Comment: Yep, I have been. I'll keep trying though. Thanks!

Comment: I asked a question in the chat if you're still willing. If not, that's alright; you've been a great help already.